# appending 3d arrays in numpy

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find dominant colors in image and then treshold the most dominant one. However I'm having trouble with data types.
My formula gives the most dominant color as:

```
color=[10,10,10] # type=numpy.ndarray ,uint8
```

But it gives assertion error when I try to convert it:

```
color=cv2.cvtColor(color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #gives assertion error
```

What cv2.cvtColor wants as an input is that:

```
color_ideal=[[[ 10, 10, 10 ]]]  #type=numpy.ndarray, uint8
```

To obtain it, I managed to manipulate color as such:

```
color=np.uint8(np.atleast_3d(clr).astype(int).reshape(1,1,3))
```

This seems working, but know I cannot append multiple colors to numpy array.Somehow, after appending the dimension is reduced to 1. My code is:

```
    color=np.uint8([[[]]])

    for item in clt.cluster_centers_:
       color=np.append(color,(np.uint8(np.atleast_3d(item).astype(int).reshape(1,1,3))))
#returns: color=[10,10,10] somehow its dimension is down to 1
```

My questions are:

1-How to properly append color data without loosing its dimension?

2-Is there easier way to handle this? I'm suprised how difficult it is to manipulate custom color pixel.

The full code is here in case it helps:

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->


    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 

    def find_kmean_colors(img,no_cluster=2):
        clt = KMeans(no_cluster).fit(img)

        return clt
    def initialize(img='people_frontal.jpg'):
        img=cv2.imread('people_frontal_close_body.jpg')
        img=cv2.bilateralFilter(img,9,75,75)
        return img


    img=initialize()

    img_hsv =cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    img_list= img.reshape((img.shape[0] * img_hsv.shape[1], 3))

    clt=(find_kmean_colors(img_list,1))


    color=np.uint8([[[]]])

    for i in clt.cluster_centers_:
        color=np.append(color,(np.uint8(np.atleast_3d(i).astype(int).reshape(1,1,3))))

    #color=np.uint8(np.atleast_3d(clt.cluster_centers_).astype(int).reshape(1,1,3))

    up=cv2.cvtColor(color,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Comment: Repeated `append` is slow.  Initial an empty array of the right size, and insert values in the right places.  Or create one with all the new stuff, and `concatenate` it in the right dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the `cv2` code, I'm guessing about shapes here.  But looks like `img` is a `(n,m,3)` array.  `img_list` is `(m1,3)`, and `clt` as list of `m1` items, and `clt.cluster_centers_` a list of m1 arrays of shape `(3,)`.

For test sake lets make a list of lists (it could just as well be a list of arrays):

```
ctrs=[[10,10,10], [3,5,3], [20,10,10], [0,0,0]]
color = np.array(ctrs,dtype=np.uint8)  # (4,3) array
color = color.reshape(len(ctrs),1,3)
```

Just wrap it in `np.array`, and reshape to 3d.

```
array([[[10, 10, 10]],
       [[ 3,  5,  3]],
       [[20, 10, 10]],
       [[ 0,  0,  0]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Or it could be reshaped to (1,4,3) or (2,2,3).

Or closer to what you are trying:

```
np.concatenate([np.array(i,np.uint8).reshape(1,1,3) for i in ctrs])
```

You don't want to use `atleast_3d` here since it reshapes a (N,) array to (1,N,1) (see its docs).  `np.concatenate` joins on the 1st axis, where as `np.array` adds a 1st dimension and then joins.

You probably could get `append` to work, but it just does a step by step concatenate, which is slower.  In general if you need to append, do it with lists, and then convert to an array at the end.

---

There are various ways of preserving or restoring dimensions after slicing.  If `color` is 3d and you need the i'th row also as 3d:

```
color[[i]]
color[i].reshape(1,...)
color[i][np.newaxis,...]
```

Reshaping operations like this do not add significant time to the processing, so don't be afraid to use them.

Comment: thanks for great help. However the same problem appears when I try to use individual color from array you created. ie: array[1]= [ [ 3, 5, 3] ] thus 1 dimension is still missing. I need to get array[1]= [ [ [ 3, 5, 3 ] ] ]. I need individual colors to be 3 dimensional.

Comment: `array[[1]]` preserves the dimension.

Comment: yeah but the process is dynamic and I do not extract color by hand. What do I do when I have array and extract colors from it as 3d? I need something that I can put it in ie for loop. for i in range(len(array)):  color=array[ [ i ] ] . This works, do you mean that? it works but somehow it looks complicated. By the way, at the end of this process, we need to combine individual 3d colors again.

Comment: What is complicated about a few extra brackets?  Define a little function that reshapes the array as needed and hide the 'complexity'.

Comment: I managed to handle this, thanks so much! One final thing: at the end of the precess I need the one dimensional form again ( with modified values) so I use ''    color=np.squeeze(color,axis=1)    ''. It works but do you think it is efficient? thanks so much again

Comment: `squeeze` just manipulates the `.shape` (and `.strides`) attribute of the array.  So like `reshape` it is quite efficient.  Same goes for alternatives like `ravel` and `flatten`.  In some cases they don't even need to make a copy.